# What is the name of the function to show page view count in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, codex

I know  **get_the_date()**  is show Date of post. 
I know  **get_the_id()**  is show ID of post.

**But I don't know name of the function to get the numebr of page views**

Please help me to find name of this function.

*************edit********
Now i can find . . . . .hahaaaa

install wp-Post Views  and get code **the_views()**  in my theme  it work and work with my theme css :)

Comment: You might find this other Stack Exchange site more useful: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/33460/how-to-display-number-of-page-views-on-a-post

Comment: thank  Synchro  i install  wp-Post and getcode  the_views()  in my theme it work and have function not count admin and bot , I love it :)

Answer (score 0):

WordPress doesn't have a default page view count function. You can use a plugin to accomplish this, something like [Page Views Count](https://wordpress.org/plugins/page-views-count/).

Comment: Thank you.  In page-views-count plugin  is file pvc_class.php this show the page number, but i want to call page number to my theme index.php  NOt showing with default plugin. Please help me :)

Comment: I don't understand your question. Please clarify.